# Conflicting Foreign Key SSMS

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to insert my CSV into my tables. I have a table called Income that looks like this:

```
Create table Income
(
    incomeID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    income_bracket varchar(100) NOT NULL,

);
```

There are only 2 rows in this table. Its `<=50K` and `>50K`. Therefore there are only 2 Ids. My CSV file also shows that there are only 2 rows. This is my foreign key constraint:

```
AlTER TABLE IncomeFacts ADD CONSTRAINT 
FK_incomeID FOREIGN KEY (incomeID)REFERENCES Income(incomeID);
```

*NOTE* - `IncomeFacts` is my facts table

When inserting in SQL I have the following:

```
BULK INSERT  [US_AdultIncome].[dbo].[Income] FROM '$(SqlPathAdultIncome)IncomeTable.csv'
WITH (
    CHECK_CONSTRAINTS,
    --CODEPAGE='ACP',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    DATAFILETYPE='char',
    FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
    ROWTERMINATOR='\n',
    --KEEPIDENTITY,
    TABLOCK
);
```

The first row is a header so I skip that.

However I get this error:

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 125
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_incomeID". The conflict occurred in database "US_AdultIncome", table "dbo.Income", column 'incomeID'.
```

I know what the error means but I can see anywhere why this isnt working.

Comment: Generally most people do not expect a CSV file to contain ID values that are generated within the database itself. Usually we see that the natural keys for the tables involved and the import process must convert the natural key to the synthetic one in some fashion. BULK INSERT will not automatically do this for you, if that is your expectation.

Comment: Turn off the FK, let the data be inserted and inspect it.

Answer (score -1):

try checking the column (incomeID) data type in table IncomeFacts whether it has the same conditions, like varchar not null or what